# Can nsIAlertsService be persistent?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I'm working on a firefox extension and I'm using nsIAlertsService for some notifications. By default, the notification has a timeout of 6 seconds. Can I make this notification persistent?

Answer (score 0):

No, this timeout is [hardcoded](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/866ef7425e08/toolkit/components/alerts/resources/content/alert.js#l49). If you need a persistent notification then you should create one yourself, e.g. using [`<xul:panel>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel).